# How do you integrate Marketo Munchkin code to fire on each route of Angular 2 SPA?

Tags: angular, marketo

Following this article, http://developers.marketo.com/blog/single-page-application-web-tracking-with-munchkin/, I implemented the code to fire on click events. Everything seems to work, but I don't see the tracking in the reports section of Marketo. Anyone else have luck firing munchkin code in your Angular 2 SPA?

Here's the code I'm using after I initialize the munchkin code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click',function(e){
       var urlThatWasClicked = e.target.href;
       console.log(urlThatWasClicked);
       if(typeof(urlThatWasClicked) != 'undefined'){
            Munchkin.munchkinFunction('clickLink', { href: urlThatWasClicked});
       }
  });
});

</script>
```

This seems to fire but not getting anything in the reports other than the first page load.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this question would be much better if you provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as well as what you've tried, any error message you received, etc.